# Services: make pop-up containing selected text as part of URI

Tags: automator, services, dictionary

I’d like to create a lookup for words/phrases not available in "Look-up" or "Translate" (Greek, for example).

This requires making the selected text part of the URI.  But it seems Automator’s "website popup" only allows feeding it a **complete** URI or the selected text.  (And I don't see a way to type the URI.)

I've fiddled with "Get Value of Variable" and "Get specified URLs" but still no luck.

Alternative is building my own dictionary—but that's only one specific language.  And if I try to find a Greek dictionary in the app store, it offers me iPad apps.

Comment: If you are just getting selected text, you would need to use other actions (such as `Run AppleScript`) to build the complete URLs and pass them to the `Website Popup` action.